# How to add Font with ITextRender in Java

Tags: java, html, pdf, arabic

I want to generate a Pdf from a Html file
I used ITextRenderer.
The PDf is generated without problems in english and french
I have a problem to generate an Arabic Pdf the characters in Arabic are not shown.
I tried to add a font that supports the Arabic, but it seemes that  the font is not applied (the font already exists in my PC)

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();                   
        if (language.equals("fr")) {
            
template = "LocationBillTemplateFr";

        } else if (language.equals("en")) {

            template = "LocationBillTemplateEn";

        } else {

            template = "LocationBillTemplateAr";

    
            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\simpbdo.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            
        }
        TemplateEngine templateEngine = PdfGenerationUtils.prepareTemplateHtmlWithPdf();

        String renderedHtmlContent = templateEngine.process(template, context);
        String xHtml = PdfGenerationFromHtmlUtils.convertToXhtml(renderedHtmlContent);
        
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(xHtml, PdfGenerationFromHtmlUtils.baseUrl());
        renderer.layout();
        String absolutePath = environment.getProperty("app.payment.receipt.location.folder");

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(

                absolutePath + File.separator + "Payment" + subscriptionId + ".pdf");
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
  
        outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Could you please provide the source code as formatted text rather than a screenshot?